# Typescript/React functional component's props function - what type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, functional-programming, components

I'm new to React and wondering how to change this code so that I'm **not using *any* for the add function** that is DI'd into the component.

Most of what I read says to use the React mouse click event type but that has only 1 param and isn't really what is going on anyway so seems bad two different ways.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface IProps {
  count?: number;
  incrementBy?: number;
  onClick: any;
  // EDIT - FIX - correct fn type
  //              I also took optional ? off types in app
  //onClick: (count: number, incrementBy: number) => void;
}

const Description2: React.FC<IProps> = (props: IProps) => (
    <div>
    <p>My favorite number is {props.count}, incrementBying by {props.incrementBy}</p>
    <button 
        onClick={() => props.onClick(props.count, props.incrementBy)}
    >
        Increase
    </button>
  </div>
);

const App: React.FC = () => {

  //initialize state
  const increase = 4;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(increase);
  const [user, setUser] = useState("world");

  const add = (currentCount: number, bump: number) => {
    setCount(currentCount + bump);
  };

  return (
    <div >
          <Description2
          count={count}
          incrementBy={increase} 
          onClick={add} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct type would be:

```
  (count: number, incrementBy: number) => any
```

Comment: I think the final param should be void instead of any - just to get rid of any. Yes?

Comment: Yes, you could use that too. I just use `any` as the return value is ignored, so it does not matter wether the function returns something or not.